# Print next record following the pattern "$JBOSS_HOME"

Tags: bash, grep

$JBOSS_HOME=/home/user/app -----line from file.

I want to grep only /home/user/app as the output from the file.
I tried but it not working

Comment: `sed 's/$JBOSS_HOME=//' file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `grep`:

```
grep -Po -m 1 '\$JBOSS_HOME=\K(.+)' file
```

outputs

```
/home/user/app
```

- `-m 1` - stops at the first matching line
- `-P` - use Perl compatible regular expression
- `-o` - display only the matched part
- `\K` reset the regular expression match to start after `=`

Comment: Just updated the answer to make sure we look for the exact string and also stop at the first matching line.

Comment: :- if i have another condition, like

Comment: if lines like $JBOSS_HOME=/home/user/app /home/dest/ and want to print same output .. will it print same out put ?

Comment: Nope.  You need to use `cut` to get the part you want.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can try: 
`grep 'JBOSS_HOME' $YOUR_FILE | cut -d'=' -f2`

Comment: it also reading next line too..  I only want print only /home/user/app from the files.

Comment: Do you have multiple occurrences of JBOSS_HOME ?

Comment: yes and multiple lines too in file $JBOSS_HOME=/home/user/app 
 /home/dest/ and want to print same outputl  will it print same out put.

Comment: `grep '^$JBOSS_HOME' $YOUR_FILE | head -n1 | cut -d'=' -f2`